# How to split and replace column in dataframe with new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'title':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Date':['1/1/2010 to 2/1/2010', '3/1/2010 to 
                 4/1/2010', '5/1/2010 to 6/1/2010'], 'Value':[1.0, 2.2, 3.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

The DataFrame is as follows:

```
df
   title                  Date  Value 
0      A  1/1/2010 to 2/1/2010    1.0 
1      B  3/1/2010 to 4/1/2010    2.2 
2      C  5/1/2010 to 6/1/2010    3.3
```

I want to split the entire `Date` column into something like `Start_Date` and `End_Date` as follows:

```
   title  Start_Date  End_Date  Value 
0      A    1/1/2010  2/1/2010    1.0 
1      B    3/1/2010  4/1/2010    2.2 
2      C    5/1/2010  6/1/2010    3.3
```

Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

By using `str` `split`

```
df[['StartDate','EndDate']]=df.Date.str.split(' to ',expand=True)
df
Out[36]: 
                   Date  Value title StartDate   EndDate
0  1/1/2010 to 2/1/2010    1.0     A  1/1/2010  2/1/2010
1  3/1/2010 to 4/1/2010    2.2     B  3/1/2010  4/1/2010
2  5/1/2010 to 6/1/2010    3.3     C  5/1/2010  6/1/2010
```

Comment: @Vaishali haha, I am lucky :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use list comprehensions for splitting columns..but now I see this answer will fail where we have different numbers of characters in the Date field. Splitting on 'to' like in the answers above is better.

```
df['Start Date'] = [d[0:9] for d in df.Date]
df['End Date'] = [d[11:] for d in df.Date]

    Date                    Value title Start Date  End Date
0   1/1/2010 to 2/1/2010    1.0     A   1/1/2010    2/1/2010
1   3/1/2010 to 4/1/2010    2.2     B   3/1/2010    4/1/2010
2   5/1/2010 to 6/1/2010    3.3     C   5/1/2010    6/1/2010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['start','end']] = pd.DataFrame(df.Date.str.split('to ').tolist())
```

You'll have to split the date column on `to`